# Deserialize XML classes to one class for writing to database

Tags: c#, xml, database, entity-framework, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize XML and save the results to a database using entity framework.

The first section of code is just to get the needed xml file from an API.
Please see below:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program semoAPI = new Program();

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            WebClient n = new WebClient();


            //Bid Ask Curves
            var bidAskCurves = n.DownloadString("https://reports.semopx.com/api/v1/documents/static-reports?" +
            "page=1&page_size=1&order_by=ASC&ReportName=Bid/Ask%20Curves&Group=Market%20Data");

            semoReports = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SemoReports>(bidAskCurves);

            Console.WriteLine("Bid Ask Curves Report: ");

            Console.WriteLine(semoReports.ResourceBaseUri + "/" + semoReports.Items[0].ResourceName);

            string bidAskCurvesXML = semoReports.ResourceBaseUri + "/" + semoReports.Items[0].ResourceName;

            XDocument bacDoc = XDocument.Load(bidAskCurvesXML);

            //Execute DeserializeBidAskCurves
            semoAPI.DeserializeBidAskCurves(bidAskCurvesXML);
        }
    }
```

Below is how my class is setup which contains the XML Elements I need:

```
namespace SEMO_app
{
    [XmlRoot("BidAskCurves")]
    public class BidAskCurves
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReportID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("MarketArea")]
        public MarketArea[] MarketAreas{ get; set; }
    }

    public class MarketArea
    {
        public string MarketAreaName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DeliveryDay")]
        public DeliveryDay[] DeliveryDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeliveryDay
    {
        public string Day { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("TimeStep")]
        public TimeStep[] TimeSteps{ get; set; }
    }

    public class TimeStep
    {
        public string TimeStepID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Purchase")]
        public Purchase[] Purchases { get; set; }
    }

    public class Purchase
    {
        public string Price { get; set; }

        public string Volume { get; set; }
    }
}
```

From here i would like to deserialize the XML and save the information to a database, below is the code I have so far which deserialize's the XML and gives the results back fine in the console.writesection.

However I am unable to save these values to the database table. The code complies and executes fine and a the database table updates, however the table only contains a report id column. Where I would like it to contain the items listed in the console.write section.

```
        private void DeserializeBidAskCurves(string filename)
    {
        //Visual only not needed
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Reading BidAskCurves XML File");
        Console.WriteLine("===========================================================");

        // Create an instance of the XmlSerializer.
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BidAskCurves));

        // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
        BidAskCurves item;

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename))
        {
            // Call the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
            item = (BidAskCurves)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            //Write out the properties of the object. (Visual Only, not needed)
            Console.Write(
                item.MarketAreas[0].MarketAreaName + "\t" +
                item.MarketAreas[0].DeliveryDays[0].Day + "\t" +
                item.MarketAreas[0].DeliveryDays[0].TimeSteps[0].TimeStepID + "\t" +
                item.MarketAreas[0].DeliveryDays[0].TimeSteps[0].Purchases[0].Price + "\t" +
                item.MarketAreas[0].DeliveryDays[0].TimeSteps[0].Purchases[0].Volume);


            //write the properties to the db 
            using (SEMOContext context = new SEMOContext())
            {
                context.BidAskCurvesReports.Add(item);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Link to xml file:** https://reports.semopx.com/documents/BidAskCurves_NI-IDA3_20190401_20190401161933.xml

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: "However I am unable to save these values to the database table." What is hindering you? Do you get any exception? Unexpected results?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i will edit the question now, the code complies fine and a the database table updates, however the table only contains a report id column.

Comment: How the `SemoReports` type looks like?

Comment: ` namespace SEMO_app
{
    public class SemoReports
    {
        public string ResourceBaseUri { get; set; }

        public Item[] Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string ResourceName { get; set; }

        public DateTime PublishTime { get; set; }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, it's hard to know what's the problem actually is?

But after visiting URI generated by

```
string bidAskCurvesXML = semoReports.ResourceBaseUri + "/" + semoReports.Items[0].ResourceName;
```

And that is `https://reports.semopx.com/documents/BidAskCurves_NI-IDA3_20190401_20190401161933.xml`

So, The class structure that you are using is different than xml generated by URI.

You need to use below class structure for your xml

```
[XmlRoot("Purchase")]
public class Purchase
{
    [XmlElement("Price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Sell")]
public class Sell
{
    [XmlElement("Price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("TimeStep")]
public class TimeStep
{
    [XmlElement("TimeStepID")]
    public string TimeStepID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Purchase")]
    public List<Purchase> Purchase { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Sell")]
    public List<Sell> Sell { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("DeliveryDay")]
public class DeliveryDay
{
    [XmlElement("Day")]
    public string Day { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TimeStep")]
    public List<TimeStep> TimeStep { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("MarketArea")]
public class MarketArea
{
    [XmlElement("MarketAreaName")]
    public string MarketAreaName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("DeliveryDay")]
    public DeliveryDay DeliveryDay { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("BidAskCurves")]
public class BidAskCurves
{
    [XmlElement("MarketArea")]
    public MarketArea MarketArea { get; set; }
}
```

And after using above class structure with XmlSerializer there are total 12 timestamp available

**Usage:**

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BidAskCurves));

BidAskCurves item;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("https://reports.semopx.com/documents/BidAskCurves_NI-IDA3_20190401_20190401161933.xml"))
{
    item = (BidAskCurves)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    //Your code to add above parsed data into database.
}
```

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]

**Edit1:**

To add first purchase's volume and price and sell's volume and price then,

```
...

item = (BidAskCurves)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

foreach (var ts in item.MarketArea.DeliveryDay.TimeStep)
{
    BidAskCurvesData bidAskCurvesData = new BidAskCurvesData
    {
        ReportID = 123,
        MarketAreaName = item.MarketArea.MarketAreaName,
        Day = item.MarketArea.DeliveryDay.Day,
        TimeSetID = ts.TimeStepID,
        PurchasePrice = ts.Purchase[0].Price,
        PurchaseVolume = ts.Purchase[0].Volume,
        SellPrice = ts.Sell[0].Price,
        SellVolume = ts.Sell[0].Volume
    };

    using (SEMOContext context = new SEMOContext())
    {
        context.BidAskCurvesReports.Add(item);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with that! I was actually struggling to come up with a way on how to access all of those timestamps. Would you have any suggestion on how to write this information to a database table from here? Thanks again for your help XML deseralization is all new to me lol :)

Comment: You can use `foreach` to all 12 timestamps to insert into db. But before that I really don't know much more about what data you want to insert into db and what' your entity look like and whats the columns table have. So kindly provide this info to help you.

Comment: I set up a sample class containing the information i would like to store in the database table: https://ibb.co/FBL1xd6

Comment: Your class contains only single `PurchasePrice`, `PurchaseVolume`, `SellPrice`, `SellVolume` but in each timestep there are lots of `purchase` and `sell` data so which one will be extracted from those **OR** all `purchase` and `sell` data mapped to your entity and inserted to database ony by one?

Comment: If you look through timestepid `18HH1` there are 6 purchase and 20 sell but  in your class `BidAskCurvesData` there are only one property for each of `PurchasePrice`, `PurchaseVolume`, `SellPrice`, `SellVolume`. So my question is which values will be bind to those property from 6 purchases and 20 sells?  and same for all remaining timesteps. got it?

Comment: Yes that is correct i have only included only single PurchasePrice, PurchaseVolume, SellPrice, SellVolume. If possible i would like to be able to enter them one by one like you suggested.

Comment: Or if it is simpler just select the first only single PurchasePrice, PurchaseVolume, SellPrice, SellVolume for each timestep and it can be amended in the future if a different time step is needed.

Comment: view **Edit 1** section in answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply i only got a chance to try this solution. It worked perfectly thank you so much!

Comment: glad to hear that it woks for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            //Bid Ask Curves
            var bidAskCurves = webClient.DownloadString("https://reports.semopx.com/documents/BidAskCurves_NI-IDA3_20190401_20190401161933.xml");

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BidAskCurves));
            BidAskCurves result;

            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(bidAskCurves))
            {
                // here it is
                result = (BidAskCurves)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

and xml objects:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Purchase")]
public class Purchase
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sell")]
public class Sell
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "TimeStep")]
public class TimeStep
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TimeStepID")]
    public string TimeStepID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Purchase")]
    public List<Purchase> Purchase { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sell")]
    public List<Sell> Sell { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DeliveryDay")]
public class DeliveryDay
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Day")]
    public string Day { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TimeStep")]
    public List<TimeStep> TimeStep { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "MarketArea")]
public class MarketArea
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MarketAreaName")]
    public string MarketAreaName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DeliveryDay")]
    public DeliveryDay DeliveryDays { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "BidAskCurves")]
public class BidAskCurves
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MarketArea")]
    public MarketArea MarketAreas { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

loop over the result:

```
foreach (var item in deliveryDays.TimeStep)
{
    // var day = deliveryDays.Day
    var timeStep_Purchase = item.Purchase;
    var timeStep_Sell = item.Sell;
    var timeStep_Id = item.TimeStepID;
}
```